# Reference a list to a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, extract

I have a list of links that each has a number of pages in it. I found the number of pages in each subcategory but now I want to make a loop in order to iterate to all the pages of the sublinks. So the first category of the link would have 8 pages the second link will  have 6 pages and so forth.

```
lists = [8, 6, 5, 13, 10, 16, 13, 15, 4, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6, 6, 8, 9, 8, 3, 8, 8, 1, 6, 3, 2, 15, 5, 4, 2, 12, 18, 5, 2]

import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import urllib.parse
import re


#source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com/').read()
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://messageboards.webmd.com').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['link'],data=[url.a.get('href') for url in soup.find_all('div',class_="link")])
lists =[]
lists2=[]
lists3=[]
page_links = []


for i in range(0,33):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    req = urllib.request.Request(link)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
    temp1=re.findall(r'Filter by</span>(.*?)data-pagedcontenturl',str(respData))
    temp1=re.findall(r'data-totalitems=(.*?)data-pagekey',str(temp1))[0]
    pageunm=round(int(re.sub("[^0-9]","",temp1))/10)
    lists.append(pageunm)


for j in lists:
    for y in range(1, j+1):
        url_pages = link + '#pi157388622=' + str(j)
        page_links.append(url_pages)
```

Comment: So for each `j` you want to iterate over `range(1, j + 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested loop:

```
for i in lists:  # [8, 6, 5, etc]
    # now use i for the inner loop
    for j in range(1, i+1):  # [1-8], [1-6], [1-5], etc
        url_pages = link + '#pi157388622=' + str(j)
        # do sth with url_pages, or it'll be just overwritten each iteration
```

Comment: could you explain further what do you mean by your last comment? You mean enter them in another list right?

Comment: @Data1234 well, the statement `url_pages = foo` only assigns a value to the local variable `url_pages`, but does nothing else. In the next loop-iteration, this value will be lost because `url_pages` will be reassigned a new value. Hence, you should do sth. with it, like printing it or adding it to a list...

Comment: it does not work. I did not explain my self right though.

Comment: Do you want `urlpages` to be a `list` of all the strings you build in the loop?